# Under which condition tap + drag to select works for Apple pencil (quick text select with pencil in Safari)?

Tags: ipad, safari, apple-pencil

#### **What I want to accomplish**

Quickly select text with Pencil when reading things in Safari on iPad

#### **What I'm doing**:

I've accidentally discovered that tap+second tap & drag work to quickly select text on *some* websites. It works reliably on the websites where it works at all
**Example websites where it works**: reddit, support.apple.com

But it does not seem to work at all on other websites.
**Example websites where it doesn't work**: stackoverflow, developer.apple.com

See the video for demonstration of when it works and doesn't: https://youtu.be/bKm-CaZa4Lg

#### **Question**

How do I make this work reliably/do text selection quickly in another fashion?

Comment: I'm in Stack :) and a double-click on a word selects it. Works in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: To confirm, we're talking about double-tap with apple pencil on iPad?

Comment: Does not really answer this question, but I've built a better UX for doing selection/annotation at https://twitter.com/VladyslavSitalo/status/1519102518881492992